# Switch beetween Screen on LibGdx application

Tags: java, android, libgdx, screen

i have set main class like this:

```
public class MyClass extends Game {
    MenuClass menuClass;
    ActionGame actionGame;


@Override
public void create() {
         menuClass = new MenuClass(this);
         actionGame = new ActionGame(this);
         setScreen(actionGame);
    }
}
```

and method of ActionGame class like this:

```
....
@Override
public void pause() {
    game.setScreen(game.menuClass);
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    this.show();
    this.render(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
}
....
```

and method of menuClass.java like this, when touch Play button:

```
....
@Override
public void resume() {
    game.actionGame.resume();
}
....
```

When i touch play button i wish that actionGame class return in action render, but the render don't start. I have try with setScreen, but this restart my screen, this not good. Help

Thanks

Comment: Remember, that `pause` is called, when your game looses focus, `resume` gets called when you return to the game. So seting the screen to menu on `pause` and setting it back to actiongame on `resume` does not seem to make sence. Instead you should have a method `pauseGame`, which stops the logic from being updated.

Comment: in essence it is what I did back then , right? if the logic I have to do it then what is the point to use the screen ?

Comment: I guess it is to much to write it as a comment, i'll add an answer and i hope, that i did not missunderstand your question...

Answer (score 1):

The method `pause` is called, when your app looses focus. On Android this happens, if you press the home button or a call is incoming.
When you return to the app, `resume` gets called.
So if you switch from `GameScreen` to `MenuScreen` inside the `pause` method, and switch from `MenuScreen` to `Gamescreen` inside the `resum`, the `MenuScreen` will never show, as it is active only when your app is in background.
What you might want to do is to switch to `MenuScreen` on `pause`, but on `resume` don't switch back. Instead you should wait till the user presses a button `Continue` and then go back to the `GameScreen`.
Also, you should not call `pause` or `resume` yourself, those are methods called by the framework in specific situations.

**EDIT:**
I also noticed, that you call `show` method inside the `resume` method. The method `show` is another method, used by the framework. It is usually called, when you switch `Screen` (`setScreen` in the `Game` class calls `hide` for the current `Screnn` and `show` for the new `Screen`).
Also the `render` method should generally not be called by you. The `Game` class automatically calls the `render` of the current `Screen` in it's own `render`. So if you set the right `Screen`, the right `render` method will be called.

**EDIT 2:**
A possible approach for you might be the following:
Inside the `pause` method, save the game data, as it is possible, that the user closes the app (or Dalvik decides to close it cuase the system needs the ressources). You can also call `setScreen(menuScreen)` here. This call will result in a call to `actionGame.hide()`, where you might release some of the ressources used by the `GameScreen`. Then it will call `menuScreen.show()` where you might load ressources needed by the `MenuScreen`.
When you return to the app `menuScreen.resume()` will be called. You don't need to do anything here. Instead you should waint, till the menu button `Continue` is pressed. Here you can load the saved data and the `setScreen(gameScreen)`.